# Why wasn't std::string move constructor called?

Tags: c++

I have this example:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class Test {
private:
    std::string str;
public:
    Test(std::string &&str_) :
        str(str_)
    {}

    const std::string &GetStr()
    {
        return str;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::string there("1234567890");
    std::cout << "1. there: " << there << '\n';

    Test t1(std::move(there));

    std::cout << "2. there: " << there << '\n';
    std::cout << "3. there: " << t1.GetStr() << '\n';
}
```

It gives the output

```
$ ./a.out
1. there: 1234567890
2. there: 1234567890
3. there: 1234567890
```

This is using gcc 5.1.1 on linux. While the `there` string will be left in valid but indeterminate state after the move, this implementation seems to move (and not copy) the string if the std::string move constructor is invoked.

if I replace the initalizer `str(str_)` with `str(std::move(str_))` I get this output:

```
$ ./a.out
1. there: 1234567890
2. there: 
3. there: 1234567890
```

This suggest the std::string move constructor is now used, but why isn't `std::string(std::string &&)` invoked in my first example ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should do

```
public:
    Test(std::string &&str_) :
        str(std::move(str_))
    {}
```

`str_` do have a name, is a named object, so it won't be passed to any function as an rvalue-reference.

A design choice made by the Standard committee prevents it to be treated as an rvalue, so you can't inadvertently have it modified. In particular: the type of `str_` do is an lvalue reference to `string`, but `str_` is not considered an rvalue, because it's a named object.

You must make your intention explicit by adding a call to `std::move`. Doing so you state that you want `str_` to be an rvalue and you know all the consequences of this choice.

Answer (score 3):

Because lvalue-reference always wins! That's why you need to explicitly specify `std::move`.

> It is permitted to form references to references through type
>   manipulations in templates or typedefs, in which case the reference
>   collapsing rules apply: rvalue reference to rvalue reference collapses
>   to rvalue reference, all other combinations form lvalue reference:

```
typedef int&  lref;
typedef int&& rref;
int n;
lref&  r1 = n; // type of r1 is int&
lref&& r2 = n; // type of r2 is int&
rref&  r3 = n; // type of r3 is int&
rref&& r4 = 1; // type of r4 is int&&
```

Taken from [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference).